# Simple Scrollbar Tremble on iOS 13

Tags: javascript, css, ios, scrollbar

Stumped. I am using the simple-scrollbar library on a couple sites and it works everywhere nicely except on iOS 13.5.1 (ipad). It does work fine on iOS 15+ (iphone).

I read about some other issues with scrolling in iOS 13 and everyone just says to upgrade! I have tried using overscroll-behavior and nothing. I tried vh units instead of height 100% and that seemed to work however it created other complex layout problems.

So I'm wondering if there is anything else I can do for folks on iOS 13? I located the problem and it has to do with relative positioning on ".ss-scroll" which uses javascript to do the scrollbar calculations. When I remove the positioning, scrolling is smooth except of course the scrollbar disappears. If I leave the positioning as is, the scrollbar slightly trembles or shakes the window once it reaches the top and bottom of scrolling.

Anyone run into this before?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I updated iOS from 13 to 15 and it fixed this issue. Not the best solution but such is life!